# Eine Alternative zum Ausdruck "Eine tolle Sache"

Tags: grammar, expression

> Eine tolle Sache, dass ich 15 Jahre Deutsch gelernt habe, also habe
>   ich keine Probleme zu verstehen, was sie sagen.

Good thing that I studied German for 15 years, so i have no problems comprehending what they're saying

Was ist die Alternative zum Ausdruck "Eine tolle Sache" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good replacement for "eine gute Sache" could be

> (Es war) eine gute Entscheidung, dass ich 15 Jahre Deutsch gelernt habe. *(It's been a good decision to study German for 15 years).*

Further replacements could be:

> Ein wichtiger Schritt, dass ich 15 Jahre Deutsch gelernt habe.
>   Eine wichtige Erfahrung...